# How to set custom margin in JOB TICKET for Google Cloud Print(GCP) print job?

Tags: android, printing, thermal-printer, google-cloud-print, google-cloud-platform

Working on the task of submitting job in GCP from my app & get the print in my legacy printer, all working great when I try with the ticket in this format

```
{
 "version":"1.0",
 "print":{}
}
```

Got the Output like this

[image: output_1]

But I need it to start from beginning of the paper with some margin, so I send the ticket with margin

```
{
"version":"1.0",
"print":{
        "copies":{
                "copies":1
                },
        "page_orientation":{
            "type":0
            },
        "margins": {
            "top_microns":0,
            "bottom_microns":0,
            "left_microns":0,
            "right_microns":0
            }
}
```

with this ticket, I got a print like this with cut end in the beginning so I tried with giving some values to the *left_microns* values(1,5,50,1000,10000, .5, .9) but no effect taking place.

[image]

also, I tried with *fit_to_page* option still no effect, any ideas how to set the custom margin? thanks

link reffered-> https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/cdd#cjt

Comment: have you found a solution for margins?

Answer (score 0):

Documents with big width will scale when you adjust the margins, I tested with an big width images and it scale to fit the width of paper whenever I adjust the margins.

Therefore, You may need to increase the width of the documents (image, pdf) to fit the width of the paper. 
This worked for me.